# Zend Framework 2: Pass Variable to View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created a View Helper to display latest Adverts from a Database Table. Since I have different Types of Adverts, I would like to be able to pass a variable from inside my View where I call the View Helper to show specific Adverts.

I am sorry that I can not explain it in a better way, but I am still a total beginner in ZF2. I will add the Sourcecode and hopefully this will make it more clear. Please note that I have the Sourcecode from a Book which displayed Pizza's randomly and changed it till it worked to show my adverts. I might still have Code in it which is not actually needed, so please do not wonder... Okay here the code:

**1. the view: index.html**

```
<?php foreach ($this->latestAdvert() as $value){ ?>
      <li><?php echo $value->getAdvertTitle();?></li>
<?php }?>
```

**2. the view Helper: Advert\View\Helper\LatestAdvert.php**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class LatestAdvert extends AbstractHelper
{

   protected $random = null;


   public function __construct($random)
   {
     $this->setLatestAdvert($random);
   }


   public function setLatestAdvert($random)
   {
     $this->random = $random;
   }


   public function getLatestAdvert()
   {
     return $this->random;
   }


   public function __invoke()
   {
     $latestAdverts = $this->getLatestAdvert();
     return $latestAdverts;
   }
}
```

**3. the Factory: Advert\View\Helper\LatestAdvertFactory.php**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class LatestAdvertFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
    {
      $locator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
      $service = $locator->get('Advert\Service');
      $random  = $service->fetchSingleByRandom();
      $helper  = new LatestAdvert($random);

      return $helper;
    }
}
```

**4. the Service: Advert\Service\LatestAdvertService .php**

```
namespace Advert\Service;

use Advert\Entity\Advert as AdvertEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

class LatestAdvertService implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{

  /**
   * Service manager.
   * @var Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager
   */
   private $serviceManager = null;

  /**
   * Sets service manager.
   * @param Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager Service manager.
   */
  public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
  {
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
  }

  /**
   * Returns service manager.
   * @return type
   */
  public function getServiceLocator()
  {
    return $this->serviceManager;
  }


  public function fetchSingleByRandom()
  {     
    // Get Doctrine entity manager.
    $entityManager =  $this->getServiceLocator()
                           ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $advertType = 'wanted'; // This should be removed
    $random = $entityManager->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')
                            ->findAdvertsByDate($advertType);

    return $random; 
  }
}
```

**5. Module: Advert\Module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
                 'Advert\Service' => 'Advert\Service\LatestAdvertService',
                    ),
    );
}

public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(           
            'latestAdvert' => 'Advert\View\Helper\LatestAdvertFactory',
        ),

    );
}
```

As you can see in #4 I have a Variable called $advertType. I want to set the variable when I call the view Helper in my index.html, f.e. $this->latestAdvert('wanted'), but how can I pass this variable through all my files? I just can not find a solution for it. Does anyone got a tip for me how to achieve it? Thank you very much in advance.

**!UPDATE!**

As SenseException pointed out below, that injecting a service locator into a service is a bad practice and instead I should either inject repository or entity manager into the service, I have now worked out the first working solution for the entity manager.

For that I have updated 2 Files: module.php and LatestAdvertService.php

**#5 module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(

                    'Advert\Service' => function ($sl) {
                        $entityManager =   $sl->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                        $myService = new Service\LatestAdvertService();
                        $myService->setEntityManager($entityManager);
                        //or you can set repository
                        //$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert');
                        //$myService->setRepository($repository);
                        return $myService;
                    },
```

**4. the Service: Advert\Service\LatestAdvertService .php**

```
namespace Advert\Service;

use Advert\Entity\Advert as AdvertEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class LatestAdvertService 
{


  public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
  {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  public function setRepository(Repository $repository) {
   $this->repository = $repository;
  }


  public function fetchSingleByAdvertType($advertType)
  {

    $random = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')->findAdvertsByDate($advertType);  
//  $random = $this->repository->findAdvertsByDate($advertType);

    return $random;
  }
}
```

I have tried to inject the repository but get the following error message:

***Argument 1 passed to Advert\Service\LatestAdvertService::setRepository() must be an instance of Advert\Service\AdvertRepository, instance of Advert\Repository\AdvertRepository given, called in***

I will continue to find a solution for the repository injection and update when successful.

Comment: With regards to your error message ("Argument 1 passed to...") you need to add the repository namespace to your service class i.e `use Advert\Repository\AdvertRepository;` and change the type hint from `Repository` to `AdvertRepository` on the `setRepository` method. Without it `Repository` will be assumed to be in the current namespace (`Advert\Service\Repository`) and hence the error.

Comment: Superb, that fixed the problem. I actually thought that I did not need to add the repository namespace, since I now use getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert') in my module.php and when I used this code in my service before, I never had the use... namespace. Very confusing and still tons to learn. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution:

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class LatestAdvertFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
    {
      $locator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
      $service = $locator->get('Advert\Service');
      $helper  = new LatestAdvert($service);

      return $helper;
    }
}
```

And of course the helper class:

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class LatestAdvert extends AbstractHelper
{

   protected $service;


   public function __construct($service)
   {
       $this->service = $service;
   }

   public function __invoke($advertType)
   {
       $latestAdverts = $this->service->fetchSingleByAdvertType($advertType);
       return $latestAdverts;
   }
}
```

And for the service:

```
public function fetchSingleByAdvertType($advertType)
{
    $entityManager =  $this->getServiceLocator()
                           ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

    $random = $entityManager->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Advert')
                            ->findAdvertsByDate($advertType);

    return $random; 
}
```

I tried to keep your code as close to your original as possible but please hear some suggestions about the service locator. It is a bad practice to inject a service locator into a service like you did in LatestAdvertService. Since you only need a repository for your service, just inject that one into it. If you need the entity manager in your service, inject it instead. Your unittests will thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much SenseException, it's working! I was close to give up, because I couldn't get it to work. I am now trying to understand your suggestion and will look for a better solution, even if I feel that I never want to touch this code again, after it is finally working :) Am I right that I have to inject the repository in the module.php? I will update my code above when I get it to work. Thanks again !

Comment: BTW: Since LatestAdvert gets a Service into its constructor now, you can get rid of the factory and make LatestAdvert a service itself, if you like.

Comment: Would that be the better way or is my way alright? I thought it's now a clear split up, but I would like to have the "best" way, specially when I am still learning, suggestions like yours are fantastic. I have seen this type of set up many times, a Service, a Factory, even if I am still trying to understand everything...

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ZF2, but I guess it is possible in the Config: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html#zend-view-helpers-register

Sorry, I can't be more helpful.